# Is it possible to replace Forticlient with the native Mac OSX networking tools to connect to a VPN?

Tags: macos, networking, mac, vpn

Because I don't like FortiClient software, it installs a daemon running all times, and I just really want to run the app when I do need to connect to the VPN (once a month), not really have it use some ram while I don't really need to use it.

Background: I don't know much why I need FortiClient, I just know that without the VPN access it provides, I cannot create a working connection using Mac OSX's tools.

Comment: The connection FortiClient creates is a "SSL VPN" connection.

Comment: Did you find your answer ?